# Is there a quicker way to declare multiple {get; set;} properties in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, variables

I need to make multiple properties accessible from within other methods, I'm aware that I can do it by using:

```
int january {get; set;};
int february {get; set;};
```

I need to do this for every month for multiple other properties. My question is if there is a quicker way to do this, just like it's possible to declare normal variables like so:

```
int january, february, march, april;
```

Comment: Why do you need properties?

Comment: If your class is exposing so many properties that this is a big problem, your classes probably are taking on too much responsibility. Your example of "month" properties could be far better expressed as a method `GetXxxForMonth(int monthNum)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use prop(And then press tab) to auto-write type and name:

```
public TYPE Type { get; set; }
```

Which VS will then ask you to replace the 'TYPE' and name ('Type') of the variable.

Comment: Wow I sometimes wonder what is 'prop' and now I regret not investigating it earlier. Thank you.

Comment: Welcomed! You can also write propfull(tab) for also adding a field behind the property ;-) (Can you kindly mark this as answered for future readers?)

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do this in a quicker way. Basically the following

```
int january {get; set;};
```

when would be compiled a private backing field would be created and two methods, one for setting it's value and one for retrieving it would be created. So it's impossible use this syntax as the following:

```
int january, february, march, april;
```

which just declares that all these variables are of type `int`.